# Using a writer like Excel4node, how can I make an Image deletable in Excel but still positioned to one cell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

When writing the xml format of Excel, there are three different ways to position an Image. I can use absolute, oneCellAnchor or twoCellAnchor.

If I use absolute, I have to calculate the position myself.
If I use oneCellAnchor, the image is positioned correctly, and sized as big as the original Image is. Thats fine.
Problem: If I delete the whole row or col, the image moves to another row, but still stays in excel.
If I use twoCellAnchor, the image is as wide and as high as the two cells. It overlaps either the left or top border, or the right or bottom border (a negative offset on the "to" anchor doesn't seem to work). But: if I delete the row, the image gets removed.

So I want the image to:

- be a fixed size, no matter the cell size
- get deleted with the row
- not overlap the border

..how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I chose to write this question and answer it myself, as I was not able to find an answer and do not own a blog anymore ;)

The solution I found after a few good hours was to position the "from" and "to" anchor on the SAME cell, and use the offset to size the image.
It does everything I (read: the customer) want.

Its a fixed size, can be deleted with the cell and does not overlap the border. Example in excel4node:

```js
     var pic = worksheet.addImage({
        path: './...../bla.png',
        type: 'picture',
        position: {
          type: 'twoCellAnchor',
          from: {
            col: 1,
            colOff: "1mm",
            row: 2,
            rowOff: "1mm"
          },
          to: {
            col: 1,
            colOff: "6mm",
            row: 2,
            rowOff: "6mm"
          }
        }
      });
  pic.editAs = "twoCell";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var pic = worksheet.addImage({
        path:  path:path.resolve(__dirname,"../images/logo.png"),
        type: 'picture',
        position: {
          type: 'twoCellAnchor',
          from: {
            col: 1,
            colOff: "1mm",
            row: 2,
            rowOff: "1mm"
          },
          to: {
            col: 1,
            colOff: "6mm",
            row: 2,
            rowOff: "6mm"
          }
        }
      });
  pic.editAs = "twoCell";
```